# Using destructuring assign vaules to already defined varibales

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

As per javascript.info, the below code should work,
https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring

In my project, I already have some variables defined, now I am trying to assign a value using `destructuring`
But, I am unable to run below code.

```js
// This also does not work.
let title, width, height;
myobj = {title: "Menu", width: 200, height: 100}
({title, width, height}) = myobj;
console.log(title);
```

```js
// This also does not work.
let title, width, height;
myobj = {title: "Menu", width: 200, height: 100}
{title, width, height} = myobj;
console.log(title);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the entire expression in `()` and add a semicolon on the previous line

From [Assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

> The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.

```js
// This also does not work.
let title, width, height;
let myobj = { title: "Menu", width: 200, height: 100 }; // <- semicolon here
({ title, width, height } = myobj);
console.log(title);
```

Comment: Thanks, changed my code to `;({ title, width, height } = myobj);`